# How to exclude one or two columns from label encoding in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, data-science, label-encoding

****The code is given below. I want to exclude two columns name 'Card Type' and 'Risk Value' from the label encoding code. How to exclude those? The below code encodes all object types into numerical.**
The columns are Alert number Job, Loan, City, Date, Card Type, Gender, Income level, EstimatedSalary, Risk Value**

```
le = LabelEncoder()
objList = bank_dataset.select_dtypes(include="object").columns

for feat in objList:
    bank_dataset[feat] = le.fit_transform(bank_dataset[feat].astype(str))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
objList = bank_dataset.select_dtypes(include="object").columns

objList = objList.difference(['Card Type','Risk Value'], sort=False)
```

Or:

```
objList = [x for x in objList if x not in ['Card Type','Risk Value']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Every dataset manipulation isn't done inplace by default, i would simply use the drop fuction like this:

```
objList = bank_dataset.drop(columns=['Card Type','Risk Value']).select_dtypes(include="object").columns
```